# Could someone please check my translation of these lyrics?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

Recently I've been studying Japanese and although I still have a lot to learn; I decided to try and translate some lyrics, to help myself improve and learn more than what's taught in books. If anyone could check my translation of the song, it'd be much appreciated!

Here are the lyrics:

> どこか遠くへ行きたい 電波もないどこかへ
>   ごらん満天の夜光 僕が指差す場所
>   Going towards somewhere far away Somewhere where there aren’t even radio waves
>   Watching the who sky’s night lights, I point at the location
>
> 線香花火は時間{とき}の儚さ教えてくれる
>   揺れる夏草の合唱 とても心地いいな
>   The sparkler tells us the transience of time coming to an end
>   The swaying summer grass’ chorus feels very good
>
> さぁ帰ろう君の待つ街まで
>   伝えたい事があるよ ほんの一言さ
>   Now, Returning to your street, I wait
>   Just a word of the things I want to tell you
>
> Sha la la 蛍の光よ夜空に舞え
>   たとえ僅かな明かりでも君を照らし続けよう
>   Shalala The firefly’s light dances in the night sky
>   Even if there's only a slight illumination, your light continues
>
> 「永遠という一瞬」手のひらで転がせば
>   まるで宵の月みたく切なくて脆いな
>   “This moment of eternity” Your palm rolls into a circle
>   I want to see the moon as if the tender hearted is painful
>
> Sha la la 蛍の光よ届けてくれ
>   遠く離れた場所だって君を想い続けよう
>   Shalala Please deliver the fireflies’ light to me
>   Because although we're separated, the thought of you continues even if you’re far away
>
> ねぇ、過去は忘れてしまうものかな
>   愛された事さえも 愛した事でさえも
>   Hey, I wonder if the past is completely forgotten
>   Even the things I loved, even the things I love
>
> Sha la la 蛍の光よ夜空に舞え
>   たとえ僅かな明かりでも君を照らし続けよう
>   Shalala The firefly’s light dances in the night sky
>   Even if there's only a slight illumination, your light continues
>
> Sha la la 逢いたくても逢えぬ夏の恋
>   また巡り逢うその折はあの頃の気持ちのままで
>   Shalala, I can't meet you but I want to meet you even if it's a summer love
>   Even if we happen to meet by chance again, the feelings from those days remain.
>
> 季節と共に去りぬ
>   Gone with the season.

Please excuse any extreme mistakes I've made. As mentioned above, any help at all (even a little) is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. See [this meta post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/should-proofreading-questions-be-allowed). (this was never truly finalized, but hey, if you agree..)

Answer (score 4):

As I'm neither an artist nor a native English speaker, please take them as purely grammatical advice rather than the recommended translation.

> どこか遠くへ行きたい 電波もないどこかへ
>   *I want to go* towards somewhere far away Somewhere where even *no* radio waves *reach*

I wasn't sure "there aren’t even radio waves" has the same connotation, but 電波 in Japanese is often used for "signal" or "reception" of wireless communications.

> ごらん満天の夜光 僕が指差す場所
>   *See* the whole sky’s night lights, *(look at) the place I'm pointing at*

ごらん is a soft word to say "behold" or "see", but you might only hear it in fictional works nowadays. `dictionary form` + `noun` makes a relative clause, though there are many translated lyrics on the internet that fail at this point.

> さぁ帰ろう君の待つ街まで
>   Now, *I'll return to the town where you wait*

The sentence is inverted for a rhetorical reason. The ordinary word order is さぁ君の待つ街まで帰ろう. The kanji 街 *is* for "street", except when it's used on its own. In this case it reads まち and means "town" (I'd imagine a certain area in a large city). の in 君の待つ is equal to が, [you can use them interchangeably in relative clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/7810).

> Sha la la 蛍の光よ夜空に舞え
>   Shalala *Dance, fireflies' lights,* in the night sky

よ is the vocative particle, "O fireflies' lights". 舞え is the imperative (command form) of 舞う.

> たとえ僅かな明かりでも君を照らし続けよう
>   Even if *that's* only a slight illumination, *I'll keep on shining on you*

君 is the object of verb 照らす. `masu-form stem` + 続ける means "continue to V". It's one of 複合動詞 (compound verbs).

> 「永遠という一瞬」手のひらで転がせば
>   “This moment of eternity” *When I roll it on my palm*

で is a particle for location: "at/on/in...". 転がせば is the hypothetical form (not subjunctive) "if one rolls" of 転がす ("roll (tr.)"). <s>Meanwhile, the subject of the sentence is unknown, so here I used generic *you*.</s> I'd like to assume the subject is *I*, because な at the end of the next line makes it interpretable as a direct experience.

> まるで宵の月みたく切なくて脆いな
>   *It feels as fragile and* painful *as the evening moon*

I had no idea how your translation was going on at this part. [みたく is a substandard equivalent for みたいに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24089/7810). 切ない is a sorrow-like emotion typically felt when you're missing or longing for something.

> Sha la la 蛍の光よ届けてくれ
>   遠く離れた場所だって君を想い続けよう
>   Shalala Deliver *it, fireflies’ lights*
>   *I'll continue to think about you* even if you’re far away

Same as above.

> ねぇ、過去は忘れてしまうものかな
>   Hey, I wonder if the past is *something easy to forget (tends to be forgotten)*

しまう emphasizes "unexpectedness" rather than "completeness".

> 愛された事さえも 愛した事でさえも
>   Even *the fact that I was loved*, even *the fact that I loved (you)*

Here is the tricky part of Japanese relative clause. [Japanese allows appositive relation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/7810), where 事 actually refers to the very event of "愛された".

> Sha la la 逢いたくても逢えぬ夏の恋
>   Shalala, *a summer love:* I can't meet you but I want to meet you

Another gapless relative clause.

> また巡り逢うその折はあの頃の気持ちのままで
>   *Were we to* happen to meet by chance again, *let us remain with* the feelings from those days

いよう "let's be", "shall be" (< いる "(of animate thing) be") is omitted here.

(Of course, feel free to point out my English errors and incomprehensible parts in my answer...)

---

***Acknowledgements:*** Thanks to @choco for correction and advice!

Comment: 「さぁ**帰ろう**君の待つ街まで」は"Now, **return** to the town where you wait" と、命令形でいいのでしょうか。(I'll return とかじゃなくて)

Comment: @choco 「帰ろう」は確かにそうですね。ありがとうございます。"a summer love ~" は一つ上と同じく日本語だと関係節だけど英語だと関係節にならない系（同格？）のやつです。（そもそもこの英文が大丈夫かどうか心配ですが…）

Comment: 『「永遠という一瞬」を手のひらで転がす』て、どういう意味でしょうかね・・・日本語でもわからない・・　ところで "a summer love that I can't meet you but I want to meet you" はどういう relative clause ですか？(英語では関係代名詞節にできないので "I can't meet you, no matter how much I want to. It's a summer love." とか言ってごまかすとか・・・)

Comment: (すんません、さっきのコメント消してしまった)

Comment: あと、修正ありがとうございました。

Comment: @choco 「永遠という一瞬」はよくわかりませんが月にも喩えられているので、玉状のものを想定しているんだろうなという程度です。