# What is meant by 魔法が単なる数式みたくなって意味を見いだせなくなってしまう

Tags: grammar, meaning, て-form, colloquial-language

I need some clarification on two sentences in the below.

My first question is that I am not sure what それ is referring to in **それを自分で把握**, which makes me unable to understand the next sentence.

A few additional notes to help provide context

- スズノネ is the name of the academy they are studying magic at
- The students (including the protagonist) are having this lesson with the teacher because they have their "own" ways of performing magic which don't conform to the the academy's expected way. 「将来そういう先輩たちに混じってスズノネの名を背負うためには、スズノネのやり方で力を発揮してもらわなければなりません」

> 九条要「そもそも魔法とはなんだと思う？」
>
> (students give their answers on what they think magic is and then the teacher gives theirs)
>
> 九条要「あたしは出力結果だと思ってるのね。これは九条要個人としての考え方だけど」
>
> 九条要「同じ現象を起こすにもプロセスにはいろいろあるわけで、それをひとつに揃えるというのは想像力のスポイルだと思う」
>
> 主人公「先生としての立場を考えるとそれを言うのはまずいんじゃ？さっきの説明と矛盾しますよね」
>
> 九条要「うん。つまりあたし個人はスズノネのやり方に全面賛成しているわけではない。だけど、やってもらわなければならない」
>
> 九条要「あなたたちみたいな生徒の場合、**それを自分で把握**しておくことが大事だと思う」
>
> 九条要「**でないと、魔法が単なる数式みたくなって意味を見いだせなくなってしまう**」
>
> 多分これは、俺に向けられている部分が大きいんだろうな。少なからず俺にはそういうところがあるからだ

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24089/7810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think それ refers to the same thing as the earlier それ in それをひとつに揃える, which based on your explanation is 魔法. It's saying that it is important that the students grasp by themselves what is magic.

> 魔法が単なる数式みたくなって意味を見いだせなくなってしまう

should really be seen as two related clauses: 魔法が単なる数式みたくなって and 意味を見いだせなくなってしまう. The te-form usage here is frequently used to connect two clauses. Here's another answer regarding [this usage of the te-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/%E3%81%A6-versus-combining-form-for-joining-clauses). In English, you might combine these with an `and`.

As is mentioned in the related answer in the comments, みたく is a colloquial way of saying みたいに. So we can understand みたくなって as みたいになって.

見いだせなくなってしまう = 見いだす + potential form + なくなる + しまう

Combining the two we have something like

> Magic will become simply like an equation and the possibility of finding meaning in it will be lost.